# Drupal 7 commerce ccavenue module 108 checksum+mismatch

Tags: checksum, mismatch

I am using drupal commerce and commerce ccavenue 7.x-1.2 module for ccavenue integration. I have configured properly as given in txt file of commerce ccavenue module. But when I checkout with one product ccavenue page

https://www.ccavenue.com/errorPages/Error.jsp?errorCode=108&processingFileName=ccavenue.txn.DoTransServlet&errorMessage=&cid=hjdhdf jfd

error code:108
error description: checksum+mismatch

please help to solve this error

Comment: Same issue. Any luck?

Comment: Yes I solved it by changing code as per api code given by ccavenue.

Comment: Can you upload it somewhere like github and post the link?

Comment: You can download commerce_ccavene.module file from git hub. https://github.com/yoges89/ccavenue. I tried to add mobile field with form and get it into code but not success, if you can do it update me also.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I removed the lines from 65-76 and changed the exit() to return $form. Still getting the same error. Could you please upload the working version? I can work on the mobile field once I get a version that works. Thanks again

Comment: sorry brother, I just pick wrong file from system. Go https://github.com/yoges89/ccavenue and copy the code. If you still getting error then check working key and merchant id into payment rule settings under store configuration.

Comment: Still getting the error. With the new interface of CCAvenue, working key seems to be missing. Settings -> API Keys gives the Access code and Encryption Key which seems to be something different from the working key. What do you enter as working key? Also I emailed CCAVenue and they mentioned that The post action URL should be https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction